# Run script from node.js, capture stdout, send via web socket

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am calling a Ruby script through node.js which returns data via stdout, I have managed to get node to send *some* of the data through to its web socket but I am missing lines and don't really understand much about what I'm doing. From research it looks like I'm working with a stream but I can't get my head round much of the documentation as this is all very new and over my head :(

My Ruby script outputs as follows to stdout when run via a bash shell;

```
{"element":"SENS02","data":{"type":"SEN","descr":"T100"}}
{"element":"SENS01","data":{"type":"SEN","descr":"    "}}
{"element":"LED1","data":{"type":"LED","state":"1"}}
{"element":"LED2","data":{"type":"LED","state":"0"}}
```

When run at the console everything is good - when I call it via my node.js script I am only getting every 2nd line so for example node would output;

```
{"element":"SENS02","data":{"type":"SEN","descr":"T100"}}
{"element":"LED1","data":{"type":"LED","state":"1"}}
```

My node.js script section is below;

```js
var cp = require('child_process');
var tail = cp.spawn('test.rb');

// Get updates from ruby script //
tail.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
   var pumper = chunk.toString().slice(0,58);
   var closer = JSON.parse(pumper);
   socket.emit('MAP.room1', closer);
});
```

I also get a crash once in a while with the following error as well if anyone can help;

> undefined:0
>
> ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>       at Object.parse (native)

I need to be able to output every line as received from my ruby script. Anyone who answers please use my own code as above not random examples as it only confuses me hugely when trying to understand what relates to what and 'what it means for me'. I've tried looking at .pipe but all the examples confuse me and I don't understand how to adapt them for my own scripts. What is output from ruby is JS Objects 1 line at a time, I need my web socket to emit exactly the same thing 1 object at a time.

Having done `console.log(chunk.toString())` to get a readable output
it has relieved something odd - an extra line feed or something.

Output from console is;

```
{"element":"SENS02","data":{"type":"SEN","descr":"T100"}}
{"element":"SENS01","data":{"type":"SEN","descr":"    "}}

{"element":"LED1","data":{"type":"LED","state":"1"}}
{"element":"LED2","data":{"type":"LED","state":"0"}}
```

How can I get round this? And could this be causing my other 'Unexpected end of input' error?

If I do `var pumper = chunk.slice(0,-1); console.log(pumper.toString())` then I get the output as shown above with out the odd/extra/rouge line breaks. I'm still no further forward to getting this to output exactly that to the web socket though.

I can get this out of the web socket but it shows I have \n still somehow?!?!

`["{\"element\":\"SENS02\",\"data\":{\"type\":\"SEN\",\"descr\":\"T100\"}}\n{\"element\":\"SENS01\",\"data\":{\"type\":\"SEN\",\"descr\":\"    \"}}"]}`
I need to get that back into single flat line like I have at my console...

So having done as suggested below I now get the desired output by using this code. I still get `): Unexpected end of input` logged in the console, that appears to be from additional line feeds I get from my Ruby script. Having run the script for a couple of days without crashes it *appears* all the data is getting through intact and parsed out to the web socket. I still need to read up and fully understand what the `for` is doing, but otherwise it appears to have fixed my issue.

```
tail.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
var closer = chunk.toString()

var sampArray = closer.split('\n');

 for (var i = 0; i < sampArray.length; i++) {
  try {
   var newObj = JSON.parse(sampArray[i]);
socket.emit('MAP.room1', newObj);
   } catch (err) {
console.log('): ' + err.message);
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean up - though the diff showed loads of changes I can't see. Just to help the `.slice(0,58)` I had to add to ensure the correct amount of `chunk` was sent to the JSON.parse - this may be the cause of my crashes. I tried using .split('\n') but that didn't appear to work as expected either.

Comment: Can you just `console.log(chunk)` prior to slicing it or JSON parsing it?  It would be good to see what it outputs to see if it is indeed dropping every other line.

Comment: So based on that output, I don't think you need to add the `toString()` nor the `slice()` you have above, just simply take it and feed it to the `JSON.parse`.  As for that, only send it to `JSON.parse` if there's something there, so check `if (chunk)` first.  And surrounding it with try/catch is `try { JSON.parse(chunk); } catch (error) { console.error(error); }`

Comment: It chokes on something with that :(

`undefined:2
{"element":"SENS01","data":{"type":"SEN","descr":"    "}}
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.parse (native)`

I'm sure I've been here before and that's why I added the other lines. Yep every update kills it with the same error. Actually on closer inspection it looks like it reads the 1st line ok then dies on the 2nd line. It never outputs the 1st line, just the parse error.

Comment: With a try/catch I now see `[SyntaxError: Unexpected token {]` Couldn't find anything helpful on `if` but I'm not 100% sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: Now I'm back to the point of not understanding again :( and feels like I've come backwards from what worked before because I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to use `JSON.parse()` for each data chunk, then you need to pre-parse each chunk on the newline `\n`.

`JSON.parse` cannot parse multiple objects separated by newline as 2 distinct objects **in the same string.**

These are *individually* valid:

```
"{\"element\":\"SENS02\",\"data\":{\"type\":\"SEN\",\"descr\":\"T100\"}}"
"{\"element\":\"SENS02\",\"data\":{\"type\":\"SEN\",\"descr\":\"T100\"}}\n"
"{\"element\":\"SENS02\",\"data\":{\"type\":\"SEN\",\"descr\":\"T100\"}}\r\n"
```

This is not:

```
"{\"element\":\"SENS02\",\"data\":{\"type\":\"SEN\",\"descr\":\"T100\"}}\n{\"element\":\"SENS01\",\"data\":{\"type\":\"SEN\",\"descr\":\"    \"}}"
```

If the intent is to parse the entire data structure then you need to reorganize the output of your ruby script to something similar to below.

```
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "name": "SENS02",
            "data": {
                "type": "SEN",
                "descr": "T100"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "SENS01",
            "data": {
                "type": "SEN",
                "descr": "    "
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "LED1",
            "data": {
                "type": "LED",
                "state": "1"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "LED2",
            "data": {
                "type": "LED",
                "state": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

### How You Might Parse the Input (Rough Example)

```
var sample = "{\"element\":\"SENS02\",\"data\":{\"type\":\"SEN\",\"descr\":\"T100\"}}\n{\"element\":\"SENS01\",\"data\":{\"type\":\"SEN\",\"descr\":\"    \"}}\n{\"element\":\"LED1\",\"data\":{\"type\":\"LED\",\"state\":\"1\"}}\n{\"element\":\"LED2\",\"data\":{\"type\":\"LED\",\"state\":\"0\"}}";

var sampArray = sample.split('\n');

for (var i = 0; i < sampArray.length; i++) {
    try {
        var newObj = JSON.parse(sampArray[i]);
        // socket.emit(newObj);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('): ' + err.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually looking that that I think I need to go the pre-parsing route if you can help. I don't think I'm quite ready to try and re-work the ruby script at the moment and actually for what I'm doing at the moment individual lines is exactly what I need. At least I now understand a little more what's going on with it, just need some help to work out how to split the lines as you suggest within node.js its self. Or at a push if there is something simple I can do to my ruby script to ensure things are only ever output as 1 line per object.

Comment: If the expected format uses the `\n`, then a split would be the simplest way to do it. Loop on the results and try `JSON.parse()` on each item. Then you can do a `socket.emit()` for each result.

Comment: Do you have an example of a loop which I can modify for my code? I'm still trying to get my head round a lot of this and it's not too easy

Comment: Added a rough example

Comment: A million thanks :) It's basically working, though I'm getting `): Unexpected end of input` come up quite a bit in the console log. I need to check tomorrow if I'm missing any data but this has progressed me forward and looks at a glance I'm getting more lines than before! I'll update my question with my code example tomorrow some time. I also need to do some reading up and check what your sample code did for me.

Comment: I would suggest using console.log to output the 'chunk' before parsing to make sure that its the expected input. It could be cut off or partly missing.

Comment: It looks like the error is just an additional new (empty) line feed being received by node from the ruby script - the data sent from the socket appears to match the `chunk` and it's been running all day without a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Try `spawn`ing you ruby script, `exec` is buffering the output and that just might be the reason for what you're seeing.

[See](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)

P.S

Wrap `JSON.parse` with a `try-catch` block and print the data for which it failed when it fails

Comment: So if I do that do I need to change anything else in my code besides replace `cp.exec` with `cp.spawn` ?   As for wrap `JSON.parse` with a `try-catch` can you point me to an example, or example with my code please as I don't fully understand.

Comment: Tried that - updated my code as you recomended with spawn - But I'm still missing lines when called through my node.js script.